# CSS bug in moderator tools?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, rendering

The 'flags' part of the SO 10k tools looks strange in Safari 4.0.5 (Snow Leopard 10.6.3):

Can anyone reproduce this?

[all your unicorns are belong to us http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/334/screenshot20100415at223.png](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/334/screenshot20100415at223.png)

**Edit:** This can probably only be witnessed live temporarily @the SO 10k flags page since (as user mmyers quite eloquently noticed) this is probably related to extremely long parts (not seperated by whitespace) in question titles.

Comment: Have you already done the obvious things? Clearing cache, checking the default fonts of your browser, installing a real browser, getting a life?

Comment: 1: yes, 2: yes, 3: define 'real browser' please 4. euhmmm not really sure about this one ...

Comment: @Lady, why the Webkit hate? (You don't seem to like Chrome, Safari nor Konqueror.)

Comment: Same on Google Chrome

Comment: @Chris: 1: good boy,2: at least you know where to look, 3: because 1 and 2 haven't solved your problem: not yours! 4: you failed! @json: Separate from these browsers, it seems I do not like you either.

Comment: If someone makes me a temporary mod or 10k user I'd be happy to attempt to reproduce this. :D

Comment: @Lady: you prefer XML?

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: If I fail at having a life for posting a question on meta, what does that say about you (for commenting thus caring about these questions)?

Comment: I can't see the picture here, but when I just went to check the moderator tools, there was a question with a [long title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648634/doctrine-table-exception-unknown-relation-alias-shoestable-in-home-public-html) that breaks the layout. Is that related at all?

Comment: @Christophe: Hey, don't change the topic! We are talking about you here!

Comment: @mmyers: good catch, could indeed be the culprit for breaking this in the moderator tools page too; did not notice it (currently near the bottom of the flags page).

Comment: I'm thinking the long title is the issue. Why? Because I don't have 10K on SO, but do on Meta, and just tested it -- admittedly I'm one minor point release lower on both MacOS and Safari than you, though. On Safari 4.0.4, Mac OS X 10.6.2 Meta's /tools/flagged page looks fine. I'll probably run Software Update tonight and report back.

Comment: @mmyers: yep, that's absolutely the issue. Page two of the flags list doesn't render incorrectly.

Comment: Confirmed. I have just edited (and then reverted) the offending title and the rendering bug didn't occur when the title was shortened.

Comment: Ok, @mmyers, answer the question, get the check mark (and some upvotes). @Yacoby: change that title again. @Jeff: where are you? `status-bydesign` is missing!

Comment: @Lady: Was going to, but merely finding the cause doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is browser specific behaviour. The part which caused it was a very long and unbreakable "word" (an URL) in the column, which caused the table to stretch to the right. Firefox breaks long URL's on the `/` and hence it looks fine in FF. The same problem as in Safari however also occurs in IE8.

Here's how the long entry look like in Safari (and Chrome and IE8):

[image]

And in FF:

[image]

Just have patience until the entry will be expired and removed, then it'll look fine :)

An easy CSS fix would be to set the overflow so that the cell would get a scrollbar.

Comment: Looks like Firefox considers `/` a breaking punctuation character where WebKit doesn't. Long-word-breaking is generally a good feature for forums to have, but maybe not so good for SO.